# In Next.JS - How can I create Typescript imports with ES6 syntax when migrating from JS to TS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-typings, importerror, tsconfig

I am currently converting a project from JS to TS. Many of my local imports are showing the TS error :

> Could not find a declaration file for module Could not find a
> declaration file for module '../../global/Navbar/###'.
> '/Users/####/#######/##########/####/client/components/ent/components/global/Navbar/cta.>js implicitly has an 'any' type.ts.

I do not want to have to resort to using require() syntax (my team prefers ES6 where at all possible), and adding "declarationMap": true to my tsconfig.json seems to generate .d.ts files for my entire repo, which again isn't ideal.

I was wondering if there is a more straight-forward way of typing these imports or any method that others may use to do this neatly? Maybe there is some config that I don't know about (I am relatively new to TS)

Comment: tsconfig's allowJs?

Comment: also make sure your outDir is different from source dir